# How to access key value pairs stored in aws parameter store using terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Requirement is that I want to pass my SSH key to the ec2 instance during runtime, which is stored in the parameter store using terraform code.

```
  data "aws_ssm_parameter" "key_pair" {                                                                          
 name = "/Test/keystest"    
}
```

Here is my launch configuration

```
 resource "aws_launch_configuration" "app" {
image_id  = data.aws_ssm_parameter.ami.value
instance_type = "t2.micro"
key_name = data.aws_ssm_parameter.key_pair.value
security_groups = [ aws_security_group.sg_web.id ]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<USER_DATA
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
cd /var/www/html
echo "MyGoogle-2" > index.html
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
  USER_DATA

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}
```

**when i execute the above tf code i'm getting the below error**

```
Error creating launch configuration: ValidationError: 1 validation error detected: 
Value 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBBBnLT+Q2ga26mv4coeobj4flEDtX/lfmP4tCWYhMW868UqHIJw4C+Ns1yh3Ondp1sW094UR6NCJHKJeGkFrzB7/EaPKLt/z3wJceIsXKSsqS539YiaslIY54t7fDpM0qcE/Y6K+zS21lGLEuAys/OwgutZGgFxDSDWtTleU0kRvnI4MVsPtWLMu4AzfvrlHrYkv2fGiwfJzq/UjnF+TvHTPoYMp3TImjvhLzrmL1y2XrWesj7Q1E1xsgMgs4N5WIbXGI45KuRBcJVNmSpw/quv5vz/3NxtRQwmQcPriJo+Fucj14+UsW+CD3agbPn4arh4PE8E2Gel Test' at 'keyName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 255
│       

status code: 400, request id: f5bf125c-54b8-4bf5-ad13-aead7176f3a3
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to write any TF code for that?

Comment: Well then share the code and explain why it does not work with error messages.

Comment: @Marcin updated the question, Could you please look into it. it's my bad for not providing the proper details.

Comment: The error is about "launch configuration", yet no launch configuration is shown in your code.

Comment: @Marcin I'm getting the AMI ID from the parameter store but couldn't get this key-pair value from parameter store... Hope you got my problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing ssh key data to key_name. You have to pass ssh key name to key_name. Now if you need ssh key  inside EC2. Pass it using user data. Install AWS cli then use ssm get parameters to get key in EC2.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your `key_name` is wrong. You are trying to pass an ssh key to it, but it should be a name, e.g. "MyKeyPair", which you create using [aws_key_pair](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/key_pair). This is where you specify your `public_key`.

Comment: Requirement is that I want to pass my SSH key to the ec2 instance during runtime,  which is  stored in the parameter store  using terraform code , Is my requirement is meaningful/ Is it possible to store SSH key in the parameter store in type secure string.

Comment: @JayaKrishna Then you have to do it using user_data only.

Comment: If possible could you please elaborate with sample code.